# How to interact with an application whose window does not fit entirely on screen

Tags: windows, zoom

I have a Windows application whose window is larger than my screen and it is not resizable. Some important buttons are not accessible at the bottom, and I can't move the window higher than the top of my screen.

The application does not have keyboard shortcuts. I am not able to get a larger screen in this particular instance.

How could I access the buttons at the bottom of the window? Is there something like Windows Magnifier, but for zooming *out*?

Comment: Try to pin it on one side or the other (or top, or bottom) using the "Windows- Arrows" combo. That way, you might be able to double-click the title bar and maximize it the right way, or resize it to your liking.

Comment: Good idea, and that may help others with this problem! The application does not support resizing, maximizing, or pinning, unfortunately. It is custom software with a UI that wasn't implemented properly.

Comment: You're making things difficult! :-) OK, how about this: when the app in question is in focus (in the foreground), Alt-F4 to close it (I hope there's a "Saving your work" dialogue), then go to this webpage and download this little freeware called ResizeEnable and test it on your app : https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11799/turn-non-resizeable-windows-into-rezieable-windows/ (download link is at the bottom of the page)